# How to close ImageView with back button in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I want to close imageview with back button. when i'm pressing back button its going to the mainactivity by default. i want same activity but imageview closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imageView.gone();

or

imageView.inVisible();`